# EmguCV Exception when published on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, opencv, iis, emgucv

My ASP.NET App works fine if I debug or run it on my local IIS. But if I publish it onto an IIS, it looks like EmguCV looses the dlls it needs. The bin folder of my VS project an the bin folder on the IIS are identical.

The following exception occurs:
The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
StackTrace: at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImageHeader(Size size, IPL_DEPTH depth, Int32 channels) at Emgu.CV.Image`2.AllocateData(Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Int32 numberOfChannels) at Emgu.CV.Image`2.set_Bitmap(Bitmap value) at CustomerserviceWizard.ImageHelper.DecodeUrl(LuminanceSource source, Bitmap bitmap, List`1 methods) in :line 213

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after a lot of research and grey hair I finally convinced my boss to just use an Desktop PC to process images with EmguCV.
The (quite obvious) reason for the exception was the missing nVidia Cuda GPU in the server.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar issue, maybe this helps in your case: please check your IIS application pool settings and make sure that you enable 32 bit applications under "Advanced Settings".

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. But thank you for your response anyway. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Error shown when i tried to execute EmguCV on IIS - `Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

Exception - `The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception`.

In my case, I solved this by enabling **UI Desktop experience** for windows server (In my case - Windows Server 2012 R2) because Microsoft never enabled that feature on Windows Server by default.

---

**Solution**

For **Windows Server 2008**

1. Go to Start >> Administrative Tools >> Server Manager.
2. At left side pane, click on Features.Under the Features Summary section, click on Add Features.
3. On the Select Features page, select the Desktop Experience check box.
4. Review required features that need to be installed and then click Add Required Features, click Next.
5. At Confirm Installation Selections page, make sure that Desktop Experience feature will get installed, click Install.
6. At Installation Results page, you will be asked to reboot the server to finish the installation process.
7. Just click Close, and then click Yes to reboot the server.
8. Once server restarts log in to server and server will finish remaining installation steps.

For **Windows Server 2012**

1. Go to Start >> Administrative Tools >> Server Manager.
2. At Server Manager, click on Features.
3. In the Server Manager details pane, under Features Summary, click Add features.
4. This will start the Add Features Wizard.
5. Now, in the Features list, select Desktop Experience, and click Install.

Hope this solution can help you :)

Links - [Solution from GitHub](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/58#issuecomment-348675692) & [Description with screenshot](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2190/How-to-Install-Desktop-Experience-On-Windows-Server.html)