# Could not load file or assembly when running azure API app

Tags: c#, azure-api-apps

I'm calling a managed x64 dll from within an azure API app. I referenced it by browsing to it. It has a dependency on an opencv dll and some files on a data folder, all at root level with a Build Action as Content and Copy To Output Directory as Copy Always. I'm using the 64 bit version of IIS Express.

I created a test project and referenced the Azure API app to test the functionality from a test method and it works fine, both the test project and Azure API app target x64 platform.

The problem comes when I try to run the azure API app by itself, it fails with "Could not load file or assembly 'some.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

Appreciate any ideas on how to figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: When I tried to execute EmguCV on IIS, this error came - `Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`. I solved it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623386/9614380). This may help you :)

Comment: Hi @GeorgeTKurian, I ended up setting the current working directory to the bin folder when running locally and when deploying to azure using an xdt file to add the bin folder path to the system PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

To make it work while debugging the Azure api locally I had to set the current working directory to the bin folder, where the managed dll and opencv dependencies reside.

To do so I added this line to the Application_Start method in the Global.asax.cs

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = HttpRuntime.BinDirectory;
```

But this solution does not work when deploying it to Azure, so I had to place an `xdt` file inside the `D:\home\site` folder to add the bin path to the system PATH variable.

Here's how the `applicationHost.xdt` file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\bin" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```